# Deploying Django to AWS EB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

paula@DESKTOP-BKTPP80:~$ virtualenv ~/eb-virt
The executable python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist

Could someone please tell me why I am getting this error, I am trying to follow the following tutotial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb

I have some many issues trying to folllow it..can't get pass that point...

I've tried: paula@DESKTOP-BKTPP80:~$ virtualenv ~/eb-virt --python=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
The executable C:ProgramDataMicrosoftWindowsStart (from --python=C:ProgramDataMicrosoftWindowsStart) does not exist

Comment: Not a solution, but if you can, please try using linux, even in a VirtualBox. It will make your AWS interactions much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows. You need to install python and virtualenvwrapper to create a virtual environment. In the instructions it is called "eb-virt". You can choose your own name.

Inside this virtual environment, you will then need to reinstall all your Django packages (and django too!).

I think that installing this process correctly will fix your error. Post comments on this post if I can help further. I just deployed django to eb a few days ago and figured it all out myself.

Last tip: Use Python 3.7 with Linux 2 (AWS)